# VS WPF Bug: Everything defined in the .xaml file is marked as missing in the .xaml.cs file. How to get rid of the incorrect error messages?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I am working on a WPF project for years. Normally everything is fine, but once in a while VS marks wrongly every control created in the *.xaml file* as none existent in the .*xaml.cs Source File Editor Window*:

[image]

The strange thing is I can build successfully and even debug the program, but getting many error message in the .xaml.cs Source File Editor Window. All the red wriggly lines should not be there. I can see the content of `DbModeComboBox` in the Quick Watch Window, even `DbModeComboBox` is marked as error “The name ‘DbModeComboBox’ does not exist in the current context”.

This happens to any .xaml.cs file I open, cleaning and rebuilding the project does not help, neither does closing and reopening VS.

It seems like the xaml.cs Source File Editor Window is not using the information in the files created by VS:

```
...\MyProject\obj\Debug\net6.0-windows\MainWindow.baml
...\MyProject\obj\Debug\net6.0-windows\MainWindow.g.cs
...\MyProject\obj\Debug\net6.0-windows\MainWindow.g.i.cs
```

I looked at their content and they look fine.

**Question:** What do I need to do to get rid of the error messages, which should not be there in the first place ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to get rid of these errors is to delete the `.obj` and `.bin` folders of the project:

```
...\MyProject\bin
...\MyProject\obj
```

I reported this problem to Microsoft in May, but it got closed when I did not detect it anymore with a newer version. Now it happened again and I submitted a new bug report:

[developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Second-time-reporting:-WPF:-C-Editor-ca/10532548](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Second-time-reporting:-WPF:-C-Editor-ca/10532548)

In that report you can see also a more detailed explanation of the problem I found and the findings of my own investigation. Since I cannot reproduce the problem, it is difficult for MS to solve it. If you encounter the same problem, it would help MS if you can add your problem report to mine or at least upvote my report.

Comment: I just upgraded VS from VS 17.8.2 to VS 17.8.3. I am not sure about the following findings: 1) projects using DotNet 4.7.2 do not have wrong errors. At least it didn't happen. 2) moving from net6.0-windows to net7.0-windows removed the wrong errors reporting after upgrading VS. Since in the past the problem occurred only seldom, I don't know if 1) and 2) really work.